# is there anyway i can do some calculations from set of array coming from mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs

how do i manipulate data coming from my database which contains random user co-ordinate with their profile all in json format. my question is that i have all the data from my database already and also the co-ordinate of the client browser , How can i find the distance of the current client with the data got from database so that the two geo-point will end up in Kilometers` and finially loop it for display on browser

```
 address: "text"
    category: "Dealers"
    cord_lat: 7.616398500000001
    cord_long: 4.1372235
    email: "dealer@tohshine.co.uk"
    imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/uploads/1576507509331-tohshine.jpg"
    location: "text"
    name: "tohshine dealer and motors"
    services: "text"
    siteUrl: "hq.co.uk"
    tel: "2344-444-55"
    user: "5ded6cb6993cdc3e3c8735f9"
    __v: 0
    _id: "5df794581efb724528f45a80"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a project, not a question. Please start working on it in some ay and then post what portion of it you are stuck on

Comment: Please use comments, when asking for information. As this is not an answer and people might downvote and you will end up loosing reputation